# When do I need to use Authenticator to read and send Emails through Javamail ?

Tags: java, email, authentication, jakarta-mail

I am a bit confused as to when do I need to use an Authenticator to read and send email through Javamail ? [Java mail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#smtpauth) specifically says that Authenticator is not required. Just this : `props.put("mail." + protocol + ".auth", "true");` would do the Job. Yet I see a lot of code on SO and otherwise, where the have set the property `props.put("mail." + protocol + ".auth", "true");` as true and used the Authenticator as well, is this required/ necessary ? And when do we use what ?

Authenticator :-

```
private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
        String _uid;
        String _pwd;
        public SMTPAuthenticator(String uid, String pwd){
            this._uid = uid;
            this._pwd = pwd;
        }
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(this._uid, this._pwd);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never need to use an Authenticator.

An Authenticator is a way to allow your application to supply a username and password "on demand".  If you're interacting with a human, that's a good idea.  If the username and password are known in advance, you can just skip the Authenticator and supply them directly when you make the connect call.